# Intelligently 1 column or 1 row of elements without JS or Media Queries?

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive

Is it possible to, ***without JS or Media Queries*** (I know), have a set of items be either in only 1 column or only 1 row, "responsively"? So if there is not enough space for all children in one row, it would switch them into 1 column.

My thinking is this is not possible, but wanted to put it to a wider audience :) I have tried fiddling around with css columns, flexbox, and the old faithfuls display: inline-block and float. I didn't take a look if css grid layout could accomplish this.

So this

```
item1  item2  item3
```

or this

```
item1
item2
item3
```

but never this

```
item1 item2
item3
```

Comment: By default `ul`'s `<li>` elements are shown in **column**

Comment: Thanks. I've removed the html example. It wasn't particularly relevant.

Comment: **No....there isn't.** The browser needs to know **when** to do this and CSS isn't conditional like that.

Comment: What exactly is the reason you can't use media queries? Is there a specific problem? If we can solve that, maybe there is a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fiddle around with flexbox all day, but this is not possible. MAYBE you could figure something out for only 3 elements, but definitely no generic solution for any number of elements.

The main reason is that we have no CSS selectors for determining whether item fits its parent/viewport or whether parent can contain all of its children in one line or not anymore. Browser won't know **when** to change styles, and there's no style property that could produce both layouts on its own (at least to my knowledge). You have to use JS or media queries to check for these conditions and change styles applied accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and, yes, completely agree.